# API to incrementally get likes on page posts and comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

My application collects likes for posts and comments on specific pages.

Right now, when the application starts to monitor a page, it uses FQL to collect all of the existing likes from that page. However, I have not yet found out how I could collect afterwards only new likes on old or new posts and comments: the like object that I collect from the likes table does not contain any timestamp that would allow me to filter out whether or not I have seen it.

Obviously, I can trivially identify whether or not a like has previously been found or not by tracking the post_id/user_id tuple. However, this is not practical since it would require me to collect periodically *all* likes from *all* posts and comments to filter them out myself.

In short, is there some kind of FB API (FQL-based or not) that would allow me to collect incrementally the new likes on posts and comments from a page ?

Mathieu

Comment: I also noticed that I the FQL query that collects the likes never returns more than ~1000 likes. So, the 'trivial' solution mentioned above will not work for any page that contains posts/comments with more than that number of likes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "since" parameter:
https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?limit=25&since=1364849754"

more reading: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Comment: No, this API will get you only the posts that have been created since the specified time. I am looking for the likes that have been given since a specified time.